# Asp.Net Core Model binding, how to get empty field to bind as a blank string?

Tags: data-binding, asp.net-core

If a form like the one below is submitted and `MyField` is left blank on the form, then by default Asp.Net Core model binding will place null into the corresponding property on the model as indicated below.

Example Form

```
 <form asp-controller="SomeController" asp-action="SomeAction">
        <label asp-for="MyField">My Field</label><input asp-for="MyField" type="text" />    
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Example Model

```
 public class MyModel{
     public string MyField { get; set; }
 }
```

Example Action Method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(MyModel m) {
          //m.MyField will be null if the field was left empty
          //but I want it set to a blank string by the model binder
    }
```

However, since `MyField` is actually transmitted in the Http Post body I'd prefer that the model binder set the `MyField` property on the model to a blank string rather than setting it to null.  I'd prefer to reserve null for cases where `MyField` is not transmitted in the Http Post body.  How can the model binder be changed to exhibit this behavior?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Studying the ASP.NET Core code for `SimpleTypeModelBinder` at https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/1.1.3/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/SimpleTypeModelBinder.cs I could see that there is a `ModelMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull` setting which is set to true by default that is causing the blank string to be converted to null on data binding.  But the property is read only so at first I couldn't figure out how to changes its value.

@rsheptolut's post on this page https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4988 led me to a solution.

**Solution:**

The value has to get set at startup.  This can be done via this class:

```cs
public class CustomMetadataProvider : IMetadataDetailsProvider, IDisplayMetadataProvider {
    public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context) {

        if (context.Key.MetadataKind == ModelMetadataKind.Property) {
    
            context.DisplayMetadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false;
        }
    }
}
```

When it's hooked into MvcOptions in the `ConfigureServices` method of the startup.cs file like so

```cs
services.AddMvc()
       .AddMvcOptions(options => options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new CustomMetadataProvider ()));
```

Now site wide, the default for a blank field that is posted back will be for the data binder to set the corresponding model property to a blank string rather than to null. Yea!

Comment: I love you <3 hahaha why MS changed this is beyond me -_-

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7630 suggests that adding the attribute [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)] per property would work.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman -  That's a great solution if a person only needs the functionality in one or two places.

Comment: I wish we could do that for only a few controller actions and not the whole project. Adding the attribute would work, but in my case the model class is shared in another project and do not reference ASP.NET so I can't add the attribute. In previous ASP (non-core) version, I would override DefaultModelBinder, but it doesn't seem possible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the property have a default value of empty string?

```
public string MyField { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

an uglier solution to try is:

```
private string myField  = string.Empty;
public string MyField 
{
    get { return myField ?? string.Empty; }
    set { myField = value; }
}
```

I think it should work

Comment: That would have been really cool if that had worked. It'd be such a simple solution. But I just tried and alas MyField is still null. It would appear that the model binder is explicitly setting the value to null in cases where the for field is left blank.  To be sure I repeated the test a couple times observing different values in the debugger.  If I set the default to "hello" then hello comes back in the model property as expected but if I set the default to `String.Empty` I get null back.

Comment: That works, as does setting the property manually to a blank string in the post action method if the property is null but both approaches obscure whether the field was posted back or not and require code throughout the application.  What I really want is a way to globally change the model binder so that I only have to change this behavior in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my 2c just in case if you want to override `ConvertEmptyStringToNull` behavior *at parameter level* in an action method this is how you do it (works in .NET 5, .NET 6, probably later versions too):

Suppose you have an action method in your controller like this:

```
public IActionResult DoStuff(int id, string name)
```

And you want to be able to pass empty-string to the "name" parameter.

**Step 1 - add this class:**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class AllowEmptyAttribute : DisplayFormatAttribute
{
    public AllowEmptyAttribute() : base() { ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false; }
}
```

**Step 2 - use in controller**

```
public IActionResult DoStuff(int id, [AllowEmpty] string name)
```

This might be hacky way to change it, but it works.