# javascript object blank property value convert to null in asp.net web api

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Hi I post an javascript object to asp.net web API,in that object some property value is blank like bellow

```
var o={
ID=1,
Fname="Tom",
Mname="",
Lname="Wilson"
}
```

but in web API model binding **Mname** blank value change as `null` .I don't want this ,I want original value in API model.

please help me ,how do I do this?Is there any option for javascript?

Comment: You need to fix this code in your web API. Post the code for that endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

solution can be found in bellow link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44397786/4336330 for Asp.Net Core

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12734370/4336330 for Asp.Net MVC